# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException certificate subject provider uses wildcard

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, match, wildcard

I use HttpClient to send a post request. But I got following exception. How to match the host name with a wildcard certificate?
Thanks,

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'showcase.example.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.example.com, ......, C=US)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:465)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
```

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://showcase.example.com/show/send");

StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"data\":{\"detail\":\"this is detail\",\"title\":\"Hello World\"}}");
input.setContentType("application/json");

postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "key=LKAJLKJlkajsdgjalgj");
postRequest.setEntity(input);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: Your example works for me, with HttpClient 4.5 or 4.5.4 and a faked cert for `*.example.com`. But that clearly isn't your real name, and HC implements (a possibly stale version of) the Mozilla-sponsored public-suffix list, so if your name isn't actually under `.com` you may get that error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know if I am allowed to use the real name in the sample code. But the real name is https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. It gives me exception.

Comment: I can connect to fcm.googleapis.com with that code on HttpClient 4.5 (which matches your line#s) and 4.5.4 (on java 7u80 and 8u144, which shouldn't matter), except no key (I don't want a request to actually execute) so I get 401, which is after TLS has succeeded. I got different instances, 172.217.13.74 the first time and 216.58.219.202 the second, both via googleapis.l.google.com, and both give the same cert (GoogleIA2 serial 2b761d6fc471f02d) with CN=*.googleapis.com (and several more names in SAN). I don't know what else to suggest, sorry.

Comment: I got it now. My issue was that I used old version of HttpClient. I never suspected it, until I read your response. It helped a lot. It works now. FYI, the reason you got 401 is because the key is a fake one. Thank you so much.